# App won't run on emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing an android app with `react-native` I have setup my android environment however after running `react-native run-android` I am getting this error:

```html
Scanning 577 folders for symlinks in /home/user/laravel/Code/mikwe-app/node_modules (5ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library
09:23:43 E/DeviceMonitor: Connection attempts: 6
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0472Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateSigningDebug
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.196 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I have looked at different solutions on the internet advising to restart adb-server but this all didn't help.

I also tried listing my devices:

```
 adb devices
 List of devices attached
adb server is out of date.  killing...
* daemon started successfully *
emulator-5554   offline
```

However I have a running emulator:
[image]

I am looking for solutions on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Try writing adb at the command prompt and check if you leave the options list.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your suggestion

Comment: Type adb on cmd. Are you shown a list of options or tells you that the command is not recognized?

Comment: It gives me a list of options

Comment: open emulator manually and try again installing the app

Comment: How would I open the emulator manually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155460/discussion-between-raffaele-darco-and-sanders).

Comment: But did not you create an emulator from the AVD manager? See chat

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same issue when running on emulator (Linux Mint 17.2, react-native-cli: 2.0.1, react-native: 0.55.4, node v8.11.2). Seems like the emulator goes offline right after compilation.

> Procedure leading to failure:
>
> - start the emulator
> - check for the device
>
> $ **adb devices**
>
> List of devices attached
>
> emulator-5554  device
>
> Device ok, go ahead and run:
>
> $ **react-native run-android**
>
> *...some (compilation) moments later*
>
> Skipping device 'emulator-5554' (emulator-5554): Device is OFFLINE.`
> :app:installDebug FAILED

The issue does not exist on a phone. I did play around with the issue and it seems that emulator is failing for the most part of it. However, I found a tweak to start the emulator and successfully got the code uploaded and started. I did not have time to dig into the reason yet.

My procedure for the tweak is to run the **`react-native run-android`** command **while the emulator is still starting up**. Not after the emulator is already fully started. Sometimes I hit the command more than once, because it  will fail (obviously) if emulator has not reached right stage. Not the final stage, because the it will go offline again. Note that no recompilation is required when re-running the `react-native run-android` command immediately, so it's quick and emulator is not likely to start. I also **Wipe Data** from the emulator to make it load slower.

After you got your application installed in the emulator you can start if from emulator. If you also run **`npm start`** on a console, you can reload smaller changes to your app. When re-compilation is required, you need to do the tweaking again. I do not *Wipe Data* from emulator unless re-compilation is needed.

It might be worth investigating this a bit further, if there are more cases like this. Please, let me know if the tweak provides workaround in your case also. Also, note that according to my tests launching the application from Android Studio works without this problem. Therefore, using Android Studio is another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue before for me I fixed it by restarting the emulator because some times it is running but stop responding

Answer (score 0):

Skipping device 'emulator-5554' (emulator-5554): Device is OFFLINE.` :app:installDebug FAILED

Solution: *****Close everything..then connect your phone via cable and restart you project...
It worked correctly for me....***